# How to check a buffer in C?

Tags: c, linux, string

I have a buffer of size 1500. In that buffer I need to check whether 15 bytes are all zeros or not (from 100 to 115). How can we do this (if we do not use any loop for it)? Data is of type "unsigned char", actually it is an unsigned char array.

Platform : Linux, C, gcc compiler

Will using `memcmp()` be correct or not? I am reading some data from a smart card and storing them in a buffer. Now I need to check whether the last 15 bytes are consecutively zeros or not. 
I mentioned `memcmp()` here because I need an efficient approach; already the smart card reading has taken some time.

Or going for bitwise comparison will be correct or not . Please suggest .

Comment: Sounds like a homework question and it should have a homework tag.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.  Look into memcmp.

Comment: No, you don't need anything especially fast here.  A loop will still finish in a blink of an eye compared to reading the smart card.

Comment: The buffer checking will be very fast by comparison with the reading process.  Efficiency is not a problem here.  And yes, `memcmp()` is a plausible way to do it.  Are the zeroes to which you are referring ASCII digits `'0'` or ASCII NUL `'\0'` (zero bytes)?

Comment: `memcmp` isn't especially applicable.  A `memspn` or `memcchr` function, if it existed, would be.

Comment: Checking 15 (or 16) bytes if they are zero is not going to be the bottle neck in your code. Better spend your effort looking elsewhere. Use profiling to find out where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
unsigned char buffer[1500];
...
bool allZeros = true;
for (int i = 99; i < 115; ++i)
{
    if (buffer[i] != 0)
    {
        allZeros = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

.

```
static const unsigned char zeros[15] = {0};
...
unsigned char buffer[1500];
...
bool allZeros = (memcmp(&buffer[99], zeros, 15) == 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop. It's the clearest, most accurate way to express your intent. The compiler will optimize it as much as possible. By "optimizing" it yourself, you can actually make things worse.

True story, happened to me a few days ago: I was 'optimizing' a comparison function between two 256-bit integers. The old version used a `for` loop to compare the 8 32-bit integers that comprised the 256-bit integers, I changed it to a `memcmp`. It was *slower*. Turns out that my 'optimization' blinded the compiler to the fact that both buffers were 32-bit aligned, causing it to use a *less* efficient comparison routine. It had already optimized out my loop anyway.

Answer (score 1):

100 to 115 is not 15 byte, it is 16 byte.
I assume int size is 16 byte in your system.

```
if (0 == *((unsigned int*)(buffer + 100))) {
         // all are  zero
}
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior and will cause an unaligned access fault ([bus error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Bus_error)) on some platforms.

Comment: Doesn't this code just check if the address of buffer[100] is zero?

Comment: `I assume int size is 16 byte in your system.` Lolwut? Stop, did you mean he has a system where sizeof(unsigned int) == 16 bytes == 128 bits?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented like this :

```
699 int is_empty_buffer(unsigned char *buff , size_t size)
700 {
701         return *buff || memcmp(buff , buff+1, size);
702 }
703
```

if the return value is zero then it's empty